# Convert swf files to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, adobe-flash, gnash

I came accross [this](https://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/%7Enorris/cis330books/ThinkingInC/Chapters/chap1/) nice web. There are `swf` and `mp3` files.
I'd like to convert them to `mp4` or something, so it is viewable.

I tried `gnash` and `ffmpeg` without success.

I'm on `Lubuntu 22.04`

Comment: Hmmm… (I only checked one .swf) From their header display the signature of a **compressed** Shockwave Flash file (CWS) in version 6. However, the size given is not in accordance with the size of the file and worse, there does not seam to be any sort of stream encoded. It would definitely be helpful to know the application used for building them.

Comment: `swfcombine` seems to uncompress at least some of the files. But the result still doesn't generate a useful mp4

Comment: See [Convert compressed swf to mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194270/convert-compressed-swf-to-mp4) on [SO]

Comment: @ChrisDavies I tried every answer on that page before, it ended unsuccessfully.

Comment: @ChrisDavies btw. what is the right usage of `swfcombine` in my case? There is file `Lecture.swf` and `slide1.swf` ... `slide21.swf` and mp3 files with seemingly incompatible names like `Slide01.mp3`, ... `Slide21.mp3`

Comment: I suspect you'd need to see the original Flash code for `Lecture.swf` to see how the various files were used together. Me, I'd guess that the HTML, SWF, and MP3 for each Slide _N_ are intended to be rendered together. But I can't get any sense from the SWFs, compressed or otherwise, so no answer from me. Unless you want an answer saying it can't be done - and I really don't like posting definitive negatives

Comment: @ChrisDavies Thank you. The flash videos were working few years ago. So, they may be some trick, how to let it work.

Comment: Shockwave Flash is obsolete, and therefore you're likely to find that tools to process it are less common than they were. I wonder if you could run up a network-isolated copy of Windows XP in a VM with a really old version of (say) Firefox that IIRC had a built-in Flash player. You could then run a screen-capture. Really ugly but it might work

Comment: Could you please kindly edit your question to include the `gnash` and `ffmpeg` commands you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'll mention some of the paths you shouldn't take and why nowadays (as long as you're running a modern distro):

Swivel can convert from swf to images/video, but it relies on Adobe AIR, which is not available on Linux.

Gnash has a dump-gnash command which might work and you might give it a go to export a raw rgb32 30fps video, but it didn't work on my system. I'll give you the command anyways:

```
dump-gnash -1 -D ./out.raw@30
```

According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194270/convert-compressed-swf-to-mp4 you might succeed with Gnash as well.

---

But Gnash is an unfinished, abandoned project and that's why I'll show you how to do with a maintained project called Ruffle.

If you're getting the newest version of the software, you're gonna have to get the newest version of Rust and its components as well. To install that (at the time of writing) the command is:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

When I tried installing from the Package Manager I hit a brick wall, the command above gets the latest stable rust distribution.

You might also need to install Java (openJDK worked for me).

Now git clone ruffle master branch using `git clone`

cd into the ruffle folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle
cd ruffle/
```

WARNING: you apparently need a GPU for this so it won't work on a headless server :/

then run the following command:

```
cargo run --release --package=exporter -- path/to/file.swf
```

This will install the required dependencies, start the exporter and then export the slide in high quality (well in terms what quality Flash implemented back in the day... you can also play around with the command line arguments if you're not happy).

And yes, it will need to compile basically the main components of the project, but at least the end result will be good.

If the process didn't work you will need to decompress the SWFs used:

```
wget http://www.swftools.org/swftools-0.9.2.tar.gz
tar xvf swftools-0.9.2.tar.gz
cd swftools-0.9.2.tar.gz/
./configure
make
```

now `cd` into the src directory where you'll find the swfcombine binary which you will need for conversion:

```
swfcombine -d slide1.swf -o slide1dec.swf
rfxswf error: sprite doesn't end(1)
rfxswf error: sprite doesn't end(2)
```

Yes it will print out errors, but it seems to work.

You will need to go it for every slide, you can use `find`, `xargs` or similar to automate it (or maybe a wildcard if it's supported).

Then you can feed it into Ruffle like shown above.

According to your input (PNG or raw video) you might want to do something like this to combine the audio with the video:

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/out.wav \
       -f rawvideo \
       -pix_fmt rgb32 \
       -s:v 800x550 \
       -r 30 \
       -i /tmp/out.raw \
       -c:v libx264 \
       -r 30 \
       -b 160k \
       /tmp/out.mp4
```

Let me know if this works for your use case.

P.S. if you wanna do the mp3 merging in one go: https://superuser.com/questions/202809/join-multiple-mp3-files-lossless

---

Edit 1:

Please try the following for adding the audio to the image:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.png -i slide1.mp3 -shortest slide1withaudio.mp4
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152278/discussion-on-answer-by-sir-muffington-convert-swf-files-to-mp4); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.